# Alternative OpenMP construct when a target device is present

Tags: gpu, openmp

I have an OpenMP C code which has two constructs - one for running on a GPU, and one for the CPU.

The first starts:

```
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for ...
```

while the second is:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

The first one also includes map clauses for data transfer.

I want the first to be used if a target device exists, and otherwise to default to the second (to run on the host).

What is the best way of doing this?

Note, I can put preprocessor options around the constructs, but I am hoping this is not necessary.

Comment: The default behavior (unless overridden by compiler options) of the generated code would be that if no target device exists, the code runs on the host automatically (w/o data transfers).  You can force the host fallback to happen also by using `if(0)` as a clause to the `target` construct (or with a runtime condition like `if(data_too_small)` where `data_too_small` is a variable that you define and set to `true` or `false` depending on whether you want the region to run on the target device.

Comment: @michael-klemm This seems to work with newer versions of OpenMP. I want to check (as I cannot find specific examples), where on the line should the if(0) go. E.g. Is this correct?

>    #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for \
>                map(to: lower,upper,n) map(tofrom: parr[0:n]) \
>                default(none) shared(n,lower,upper,parr) \
>                private(i,j,dx,dy,dz,r,force) \
>                reduction(+: ret)  if(0) 

And this will run the "parallel for" on the CPU if a target does not exist?

Comment: The exact location of the `if` clause does not really matter, since the clauses can usually be reordered.  The correct directive in your case should be something like `#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for map(to: lower,upper,n) map(tofrom: parr[0:n]) default(none) shared(n,lower,upper,parr) private(i,j,dx,dy,dz,r,force) reduction(+: ret) if(target:0)`.  Notice that OpenMP introduced clause modifiers a while ago, so you can now be specific to which part of the directive, the `if` clause should "bind".  That's why I use `if(target:0)`.